# Toggle show/hide on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, toggle, jquery

I got a `div` element, so when I click on it, another `div` which is hidden by default is sliding and showing, here is the code for the animation itself:

```
$('#myelement').click(function(){
     $('#another-element').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

How can I make that so when I click on the `#myelement` one more time (when the element is showed already) it will **hide** the `#another-element` like this:

`$('#another-element').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);`?

So basicly, it should work exactly like a `slideToggle` but with the `show/hide` functions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### The toggle-event is deprecated in version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9

<s>Try this...</s>

```
$('#myelement').toggle(
   function () {
      $('#another-element').show("slide", {
          direction: "right"
      }, 1000);
   },
   function () {
      $('#another-element').hide("slide", {
          direction: "right"
      }, 1000);
});
```

> **Note:** This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).
>
> The .toggle() method is provided for convenience. It is relatively
>   straightforward to implement the same behavior by hand, and this can
>   be necessary if the assumptions built into .toggle() prove limiting.
>   For example, .toggle() is not guaranteed to work correctly if applied
>   twice to the same element. Since .toggle() internally uses a click
>   handler to do its work, we must unbind click to remove a behavior
>   attached with .toggle(), so other click handlers can be caught in the
>   crossfire. The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the
>   event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked
>   if .toggle() has been called on the element, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

You toggle between visibility using show and hide with click. You can put condition on visibility if element is visible then hide else show it. **Note you will need [jQuery UI](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css) to use addition effects with show / hide like direction**.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/j999y/2/)**

```
$( "#myelement" ).click(function() {     
    if($('#another-element:visible').length)
        $('#another-element').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    else
        $('#another-element').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);        
});
```

Or, simply use toggle instead of click. By using toggle you wont need a condition (if-else) statement. as suggested by T.J.Crowder.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/j999y/3/)**

```
$( "#myelement" ).click(function() {     
   $('#another-element').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder for pointing. I have modified my answer, please have a look.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't look it up repeatedly. `var elm = $("#another-element"); if (elm.is(":visible")) { /* Do one thing */ } else { /* Do the other */ }` (Your specific example would actually be a one-liner inside the click: `$('#another-element').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);` but as the goal is to show doing different things [two functions]...)

Comment: btw Toggle() is now deprecated.

Answer (score 30):

Make use of jquery toggle function which do the task for you

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - Display or hide the matched elements.

```
$('#myelement').click(function(){
      $('#another-element').toggle('slow');
  });
```

Comment: when you use toggle it hides the content, but the values are still present and can be seen on page post

Answer (score 4):

this will work for u

```
   $("#button-name").click(function(){
        $('#toggle-id').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` function instead of `.click()`....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for toggle your element 
**var ele = jQuery("yourelementid");
ele.slideToggle('slow');**
this will work for you :)

Comment: Not really, as I want to slide it to the left side. And `slideToggle` is toggling the elements vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js</script>        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome !!!</p>
<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle(1000,'linear');
  });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle)

Comment: This is basically the same code as given in the accepted answer + linked code example is not the same as in the answer.