# Jquery toggle function not toggling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggle

Hi hope you can help me,

im trying to create a toggle effect that will animate and display a element in my webpage.
however when clicking said div it will only activate the second function as opposed to toggling through the desired functions my code is bellow.

```
function toggle(id){

        $(id).toggle(
            function(){
                alert('toggle 1');
                //$(id).animate({heigt: "220"}, 500);
                //$('#sub_menu').css({"color": '#AAA'});
            },
            function(){
                alert('toggle 2');
                //$(id).animate({heigt: "0"}, 500);
                //$('#sub_menu').css({"color": '#333'});
            }
        );

    };
```

at the moment when ever function is executed only the toggle 2 alert will pop up. I need it to taggle between alert1 then alert 2 then alert 1 and so on.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310717/toggle-show-hide-on-click-with-jquery

Comment: Toggle does not take 2 callback functions, from what i know.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21520499/383904 to create your own toggle fuinction. (Toggle Method does not accept 2 arguments, from jQ v1.9 it's used to show/hide) an element.)