# change the parent div class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the parent class on click

My HTML code

```
<div class="banner">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
 </div>
```

My Script

```
  $(".submit").click( function (){
     $(this).toggleClass("banner expand_it");
  });
```

Comment: Come on, you haven't even tried...

Comment: Your code is jQuery. I added the tag. Now please search google or SO for _jquery toggle parent class_

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post code and effort - as you can see the members of SO does not take kindly to questions without any effort shown

Comment: Your event is attached to the submit button so when you use `$(this)` as a selector you are targeting the element use to trigger that event. so that would mean you are running `.toggleClass()` on the submit button and nothing else. Just like in your question you want to target the parent and I see of no attempt to find or target the parent element. I believe your real problem is due to lack of research.

Comment: sorry guys, I have tried it I have searched also but still not get the result. I know its a simple task for expert.

Comment: Not for expert. Searching "get parent jquery", and the first result on Google is what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle show/hide on click with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310717/toggle-show-hide-on-click-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery has a `parent` function to get the parent of a given element

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$(".submit").click( function (){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("banner expand_it");
});
```