# Collapsible menu in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a side collapsible panel , on clicking the arrow icon the sub contents are hidden , and once hidden on clicking the arrow the sub contents are shown.
There is a jquery code for the slide down and slide up function , is there a way by default the sub contents are hidden and onclicking the arrow the sub content are shown or hidden accordingly?
The code is as

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.active span.clickable').on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
      // expand the panel
      $(this).parents('.active').find('.collapsein').slideDown();
      $(this).removeClass('panel-collapsed');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    } else {
      // collapse the panel
      $(this).parents('.active').find('.collapsein').slideUp();
      $(this).addClass('panel-collapsed');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active">
  <a href="#">Main Data<span class="pull-right clickable "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
  <ul class="collapsein ">
    <li><label>Sub Data1</label></li>
    <li><label>Sub Data2</label></li>
    <li><label>Sub Data3</label></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310717/toggle-show-hide-on-click-with-jquery

Comment: If you need to have the suybmenu hidden at first, then you need to hide it in CSS first: `. collapsein { display: none; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `css` if you want sub-menu by default hidden. Please follow the below code, it will done your job::

**HTML**

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#" class="clickable panel-collapsed">Main Data<span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="collapsein ">
        <li><label>Sub Data1</label></li>
        <li><label>Sub Data2</label></li>        
        <li><label>Sub Data3</label></li>                         
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.collapsein{
    display: none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('.active a.clickable').on("click", function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        // expand the panel
        $(this).parents('.active').find('.collapsein').slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
    else {
        // collapse the panel
        $(this).parents('.active').find('.collapsein').slideUp();
        $(this).addClass('panel-collapsed');
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
});
});
```

Working JSFiddle:: https://jsfiddle.net/80fpe9d9/

Comment: @Esteann Please upvote the answer if it helped you and for helping others.

Comment: after load the page, on first click it not working, when click again it working fine, please fix this in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you want your list to appear hidden by default it is only a simple adjustment. You would first set the css for it to display: none.

**CSS**

```
.collapsein {
    display: none;
}
```

And also add the class panel-collapsed to your clickable span

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Main Data<span class="pull-right clickable panel-collapsed"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
```

[Working JSBin](https://jsbin.com/relacelija/edit?html,css,js,output)

Moved down arrow left for clarity.

Comment: it's not working bro. she has made some other mistakes also.

Comment: If you mean nothing happens when you click the anchor tag, then that is the way they have it set up. You must click the chevron all the way on the right that's pointing down :) I think the clickable and other classes should be on the anchor but if they want it on the <i> tag then whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!!!!
Had to add the css code for it to work properly

```
.collapsein{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Esteann that was Rana, Manuel and Flexicon told you before, please don't answer with the right answer if any user told you, just mark the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Script code with Jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
  $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")){
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

call the accordian id in html like below:

```
<div id="accordian">
<ul>
<li>
<h3><span class="icon-dashboard"></span>Dashboard</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub menu1</a> </li> 
<li><a href="#">Sub menu2</a> </li> 
<li><a href="#">Sub menu3</a> </li> 
<li><a href="#">Sub menu4</a> </li> 
</ul> 
</li>
</div>
```

Here is the [Reference and Demo](http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2018/08/simple-expanding-menu-with-jquery-and-css.html)